# visual studio returning all errors for all projects even though code is fine

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

**problem**
so I had this issue for a couple of years where sometimes when I create a file in the visual studio everything turns to errors even though I haven't touched anything. as shown by 
[this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVlEG.png)

**my computer** its a MacBook Pro with macOS 10.13.6. visual studio 7.7.4

**fixes** to fix the problem I would normally restart vs like 5-6 times and i would come right but it has now stopped working completely. i noticed that there are a lot of people complaining on other websites about this problem from 2012 and they have fixed it by removing the .sdf file, removing the .suo file, updating Xamarin Studio & updating the android sdk, using an older version of .net, clearing their ReSharper caches and unloading and reloading their project. (and yes I have restarted my computer) however non of this works for me so I'm kinda stuck.

I was wondering if anyone has the same problem or a fix I could try.

good website with people with same problem.
  https://galasoft.ch/posts/2014/01/quick-tip-what-to-do-when-visual-studio-freaks-out-and-everything-is-red

Answer (score 0):

wow after all these yes of having this problem I just updated VS and it's working. hopefully, it fixs it for good but still would be good to know how to fix this if it happens with the new update later.